# Get new/latest wall post of a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension for Facebook, what I want is to get the latest wall posts of a page using the extension. For e.g. If a user posts on a Facebook, I can get alert from my extension of the new posts (not all posts...only the new/latest posts uploaded by the user),
Can i do it using the Facebook api? Because I can get all posts using the api, but I want the latest/new post. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Facebook Realtime Updates feature here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

This feature will inform you when a user has new posts, rather than requiring you to constantly poll the Facebook API to check for new posts.